# Distributed Lock Manager (DLM) for Windows or Linux?

Tags: linux, windows

Is there a distributed lock manager ([DLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager)) feature in any version of Linux or Windows similar to VMS's distributed lock manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Red Hat [Cluster Suite](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5.4/html/Cluster_Suite_Overview/s2-lockmgmt-overview-CSO.html#) for RHEL 5 does distributed lock management.